# How to fix RenderBox was not laid out in ListTile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this row and it always throws an exception because of ListTile. I understand that I should use expanded but could not figure out where to put it in the StreamBuilder.

```
Row get upperSection {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
          stream: widget.device.state,
          initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
          builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
            leading: (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected)
                ? const Icon(Icons.bluetooth_connected)
                : const Icon(Icons.bluetooth_disabled),
            title: Text('Device is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[0]}.'),
            subtitle: Text('${widget.device.id}'),
            trailing: StreamBuilder<bool>(
              //The below stream is to show either a refresh button or
              //CircularProgress based on the service discovering status,
              //and a IndexedStack widget is used to present the needed widget
              stream: widget.device.isDiscoveringServices,
              initialData: false,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => IndexedStack(
                index: snapshot.data ? 0 : 0,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    onPressed: () => widget.device.discoverServices(),
                  ),
                  const IconButton(
                    icon: SizedBox(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      width: 17.0,
                      height: 17.0,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

the exception is:

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderMouseRegion#d2d47 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 1929 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
lib\componants\device_screen_widgets.dart:44

Comment: Can we see the exception?

Comment: I have once encountered this type of error once and solved it by just wrapping the listTile with SizedBox(height: 30, width: Get.width/1.1, child: ListTile())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
    child:StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
    stream: widget.device.state,
    ....
    )
    )
  ],
  );
```